# node_load($nid) gives me a fatal error in Drupal 7

Tags: drupal-7

Pretty new to drupal 7 and a lot has changed. How can I simply load a node and print it out? I am using the following but the function node_load gives me: PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function node_load()

```
$node = node_load(15);
echo '<pre>' . print_r($node,1) . '</pre>';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it sounds like it cant find the function node_load - which i can imagine only happening if you were trying to do this outside of the drupal framework? e.g. on a PHP page youve simply added into the webspace?

contents of file:

```
<?php

node_load(1);
```

make sure you have the node_load inside a drupal module you have created, and when its responding to a hook ( e.g. hook_view )

sites > all > modules > yourmodule

yourmodule.module

```
yourmodule_view($node, $view_mode){
  node_load(1);
}
```